# Habilitar tabulação em campos ReadOnly = true | Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Olá,

Tenho este código no evento do ComboBox, quando seleciono que é pessoa Física ele habilita os campos pertinentes e bloqueia os de pessoa "Jurídica" e vice versa. Porém ainda é possível eu passar em cima dos campos desabilitados pela tabulação/ ou clicando porém.. (não consigo digitar nada << é o certo.).

```
private void cbTipoPessoa_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Irá verificar entre as duas opções disponíves e habilitar ou desabilitar os campos;

    string opcaoSelecionada = cbTipoPessoa.SelectedItem.ToString(); //Irá pegar o valor que está selecionado

    if(opcaoSelecionada == "Física")
    {
        //Campos Jurídicos ficam como leitura somente

        mskCNPJ.ReadOnly = true;
        txtInscricaoEstadual.ReadOnly = true;
        txtInscricaoMunicipal.ReadOnly = true;

        //Campos Físicos habilitados
        mskCPF.ReadOnly = false;
    }else if(opcaoSelecionada == "Jurídica")
    {
        //Campos Físicos ficam como leitura somente
        mskCPF.ReadOnly = true;

        //Campos Jurídicos habilitados
        mskCNPJ.ReadOnly = false;
        txtInscricaoEstadual.ReadOnly = false;
        txtInscricaoMunicipal.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

O que posso fazer para resolver? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o `TAB` não focar no elemento use:

```
txtMeuControle.TabStop = false;
```

Mesmo assim ainda será possível clicar e selecionar o controle, para não conseguir clicar no controle, provavelmente só desabilitando ele:

```
txtMeuControle.Enabled = false;
```

Isso substituí a `TabStop` na funcionalidade desejada.

Comment: O .Enabled solucionou exatamente as duas coisas o "clique" e o "TAB" ele pula. Certinho, obrigado!!